# Once a version of Ubuntu crosses EOL, can no more packages be installed on it?

Tags: 12.10, software-installation

I understand that the official ubuntu website says:

> When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life” it receives no further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades. It is highly recommended that you upgrade to a recent version of Ubuntu at this point.

Does it mean that I cannot install anymore packages?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 (EOL - May, 2014).

When I tried to install tmux, doing

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

The terminal read:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tmux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to install packages through `sudo apt-get install <PACKAGE NAME>` unless you update your sources file [here is a reference on how to do that.](http://pogidude.com/2013/how-to-install-packages-for-end-of-life-ubuntu-editions/)  But you will not be receiving updates from canonical so I still urge you to upgrade when you get time.